# Multiplication of polynomials

Tags: python-3.x, list, polynomials

I have polynomial coefficients. How to get a list of coefficients e.g. by multiplying 10 polynomials?

For example for two polynomials.
(x + 2)*(x + 2) = x^2 + 4x + 4

[1,2] * [1,2] = [1, 4, 4]

I am trying to solve a codewars task which gives me a list of roots and I have to return a polynomial.
My first idea was function from numpy, poly but there is too much difference with large numbers. Thank u!

Source: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5b2d5be2dddf0be5b00000c4

My code:

```py
import re
from numpy import poly
from math import fabs

def polynomialize(roots):
    result = ''
    data = list(filter(lambda x : x[0] != 0, zip(poly(roots).tolist(), range(len(roots), -1, -1))))
    for coe, power in data:
        if coe > 0:
            result += f'+ {int(coe)}x^{power} '
        else:
            result += f'- {int(fabs(coe))}x^{power} '
    result = re.sub(r'(x\^1)(?![0-9]+)', 'x', result).replace('x^0', '')
    result = re.sub(r'(?<![0-9])(1x)','x', result)
    return result[2:] + '= 0'
```

Comment: Please provide your code and explain what goes wrong, and what you have done to debug your code. As you have phrased the question now, it looks too much as if you want us to just write the code for you.

Comment: With a large number of roots some coefficients are not the same as expected. I think poly approximates the polynomial with numerical methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely related to the integer type that numpy uses in its arrays, while the inputs and the resulting coefficients may involve greater numbers than these integers can hold (wrapping around).

You could do this to get `data`:

```
    coeff = [1]
    for r in roots:
        coeff = [t[1] - r * t[0] for t in zip(coeff + [0], [0] + coeff)]
    data = list(filter(lambda x : x[1] != 0, 
                      reversed(list(enumerate(coeff)))))
    for power, coe in data:  # notice the pairs are in reverse compared to your loop
```

Also `fabs` is limited to integer. I would change `int(fabs(coe))` to `-int(coe)`.

I submitted this solution and it was accepted:

```
import re

def polynomialize(roots):
    coeff = [1]
    for r in roots:
        coeff = [t[1] - r * t[0] for t in zip(coeff + [0], [0] + coeff)]
    data = list(filter(lambda x : x[1] != 0, 
                      reversed(list(enumerate(coeff)))))
    result = ''
    for power, coe in data:
        if coe > 0:
            result += f'+ {int(coe)}x^{power} '
        else:
            result += f'- {-int(coe)}x^{power} '
    result = re.sub(r'(x\^1)(?![0-9]+)', 'x', result).replace('x^0', '')
    result = re.sub(r'(?<![0-9])(1x)','x', result)
    return result[2:] + '= 0'
```

Comment: Some coefficients still have wrong values. :(

Comment: I went ahead and applied that change, plus a change I needed to avoid an overflow error, and it was accepted on CodeWars. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, I learned some interesting things from you

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want?

```python
from sympy import symbols, Poly

x = symbols("x")

pol1 = Poly(x + 2)

pol = pol1 ** 2

pol.all_coeffs()
# [1, 4, 4]
```

Comment: If I could use sympy, I wouldn't ask :D